# SQL - separate results of same column into different cloumns using multiple where statements

Tags: sql, group-by, subquery

I have no prior SQL knowledge. I am trying to get sum of all **debitTransactions** for different **transactionType** for each **FolioNumber**

I have the following code but it gives sum of all the debit transactions for each transaction type for each folio.
But all I want is sum of all **gst(106)** for each folio in one column, sum of all **levy(105)** for each folio in second column and sum of all **roomRevenue(100)** for each folio in third column.

```
---non working code
SELECT FolioNumber,
       (Select SUM(debitTransactions) FROM HISTTRN WHERE transactionType = 106) as gst,
       (Select SUM(debitTransactions) FROM HISTTRN WHERE transactionType = 105) as levy,
       (Select SUM(debitTransactions) FROM HISTTRN WHERE transactionType = 100) as roomRevenue
FROM
HISTTRN
GROUP BY FolioNumber
ORDER BY FolioNumber
```

Following code does work if I only want one transactionType but I want 3 different transaction types

```
---working code
SELECT FolioNumber,
       SUM(debitTransactions) as gst 
FROM HISTTRN 
WHERE transactionType = 106

GROUP BY FolioNumber
ORDER BY FolioNumber
```

Is there a possible way of doing that? Thanks

Comment: What's your DBMS ..? SQL, which has different dialects depending on database brand, is a common structure for databases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT FolioNumber,
       SUM(case when transactionType = 106 then debitTransactions else 0 end) as gst,
       SUM(case when transactionType = 105 then debitTransactions else 0 end) as levy,
       SUM(case when transactionType = 100 then debitTransactions else 0 end) as roomRevenue
FROM HISTTRN 
GROUP BY FolioNumber
ORDER BY FolioNumber
```